# how to check mail server is down in php

Tags: php

Does anyone how can I check whether the mailserver I use is down or not with php?

Comment: Ping it and see if it responds?

Comment: Ask Strong Bad: http://www.homestarrunner.com/sbemail45.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Net_SMTP`](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP/) to make a connection to the server. It won't be perfect, but if you can't connect then it's probably down.

Comment: I'd send a HELO and then a QUIT as well :)

Comment: @gnud: Hah. Yes, indeed, I should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

most mail servers are on port 25. An example using sockets

```
$address = gethostbyname('www.somewhere.com');
$service_port="25";
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}
echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}
```

See the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php) for more.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkSMTPService($hostname, $port)
{
     // Create a socket.  If we fail to create a socket return false
     // This is really more to check that we are able to create a socket
     // than if we are able to check the server
     $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
     if($socket === false) return false;

     // Now we will connect to the server.  If we fail we return false.
     $result = socket_connect($socket, $hostname, $port);
     if($result === false) return false;

     return true;

}
```